# Kotlin cannot access class of Java library, which Java can access

Tags: kotlin

I am relatively new to Kotlin and recently started to convert some Java projects to Kotlin for practice. I know the Java code is working but I am having trouble getting my Kotlin port running. It seems like Kotlin cannot access Java classes the same way Java can.

I have a class in a Java library which looks like this one:

```java
package foo.bar.utils;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Foo {

    private List<Bar> bars;

    public Foo() {
        bars = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    static public class Bar {

        private Qux quxs;

        public Qux getQuxs() {
            return quxs;
        }

        public Bar setQuxs(final Qux quxs) {
            this.quxs = quxs;
            return this;
        }

        static class Qux {

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Qux []";
            }
        }

        static public class QuxClass extends Qux {
            private String id;

            public String getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public QuxClass setId(final String id) {
                this.id = id;
                return this;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The working Java code looks like this:

```java
package com.example;

import foo.bar.utils.Foo;

public class JavaMain {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Foo.Bar bar = new Foo.Bar();
        Foo.Bar.QuxClass qux = new Foo.Bar.QuxClass();
        bar.setQuxs(qux);

        System.out.println(bar);
    }
}
```

The non-working Kotlin code looks like this:

```kotlin
package com.example

import foo.bar.utils.Foo

fun main() {
    val bar = Foo.Bar()
    val qux = Foo.Bar.QuxClass()
    bar.quxs = qux

    println(bar)
}
```

I omitted code that (I believe) is unnecessary to reproduce this problem.

The Kotlin code does in fact compile but at runtime, it throws `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class foo.bar.utils.Foo$Bar$Qux from class com.example.MainKt`.
IntelliJ shows, when hovering over `bar.quxs`, a hint that `Type Foo.Bar.Qux! is inaccessible in this context due to: public/*package*/ open class Qux defined in foo.bar.utils.Foo.Bar` but I have troubles understanding that hint.

A possible fix is to change the accessibility of the inner class Qux to public.

I tried OpenJDK 12 and Amazon Corretto 8 with the same result.

I also tried to inspect the decompiled code of the Kotlin and the Java code but could not spot any noteworthy differences.

Calling setQuxs() did not help either.

Is there a way to alter my Kotlin code to get the port running?
I really want to understand why Kotlin acts like this.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your Kotlin code; that's exactly how I'd translate the Java.  If no-one here comes up with an explanation, I'd see if it's mentioned on the [Kotlin YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT) bug-reporting site (and maybe consider raising an issue there if not).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is easy to see when you check out the JVM bytecode for your kotlin snippet (With a regular bytecode viewer, not the one included with Intellij). Your line `bar.quxs = qux` becomes:

```
aload0
aload1
checkcast foo/bar/utils/Foo$Bar$Qux
invokevirtual foo/bar/utils/Foo$Bar.setQuxs(Lfoo/bar/utils/Foo$Bar$Qux;)Lfoo/bar/utils/Foo$Bar;
```

Or represented as java code:

```
bar.setQuxs((foo.bar.utils.Foo.Bar.Qux)qux);
```

The bytecode for your JavaMain class does not include this unnecessary checkcast:

```
aload1
aload2
invokevirtual foo/bar/utils/Foo$Bar.setQuxs(Lfoo/bar/utils/Foo$Bar$Qux;)Lfoo/bar/utils/Foo$Bar;
```

Why the kotlin compiler adds this checkcast I can not say. I would lean towards classifying this as a bug or at least unexpected behaviour in the kotlin compiler with no easy fix on your end (Besides modifying the code of the library).

Answer (score 0):

New keyword is not for creating object in Kotlin
you add import like this

```
import foo.bar.utils.Foo.Bar
import foo.bar.utils.Foo.Bar.QuxClass
```

then create object like

```
    val bar = Bar()
    val qux = QuxClass()
```

Comment: Why mention `new`, when the question doesn't include that in its Kotlin code?  (Only in its Java code, where that's needed.)  And why wouldn't qualified names be just as valid as `import`ed ones?

Comment: But you are using Java class in Kotlin function. So even if class is in java the way it is going to use in Kotlin code is Kotlin way

Comment: Both Java and Kotlin/JVM classes are compiled to Java bytecode; once compiled, a class is a class, and there's little or no practical difference between them.  (That interoperability is one of the selling points of Kotlin: Java classes can use Kotlin classes, and vice versa, without knowing which language they were compiled from.)

Comment: Yes, there are Kotlin language rule before converting class file. So by those rule this is a way for your question. Accept as answer....